# Where to get UUID libraries and code

Tags: linux, compiling, uuid

What is the difference between the libuuid that comes with the util-linux-ng package and the one that comes with e2fsprogs?

Also, if I want to compile libuuid from source, where should I get said source?

- https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/
- https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/tytso/e2fsprogs/v1.42.8/

Those are my best guesses, are they trustworthy and correct?

Comment: If we can't trust kernel.org we have bigger problems than a UUID library.

Comment: I'm breaking the rules to say 'thank you', just like I broke the rules on StackOverflow by asking this exact question which got flagged as off topic because it's opinionated... *sigh*

Comment: one question per question, please.

Comment: looks like my comments can't be blocked or downvoted so i'm gonna say this (nothing personal against you): it's kind of ridiculous that we have wait 20 minutes, and expect each submission to only be exactly 1 question, no more no less... i think most people are very very capable of getting the 'gist' of things and it's easy to see that while i technically asked 3 questions, they are all very closely related and it would be more disorganized and wasteful to make new pages for each question. end rant.

Comment: @sg The point of this site is not only to help the original poster, but to also help those which follow after them. It is important to use one question per question for this exact reason -- it hinders the people that may benefit down the line. The original poster is just one of many.